# Restricting fragment size depending on fixed footer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

[image: demo design]

I am creating an android app with the above design in mind. I have made a custom action bar and stuck that to the onCreateOptionsMenu in my MainActivity.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
```

I have also created a fixed footer in my MainActivity which is basically the imageviews for triggering different fragments in the app. Now these imageviews are set to wrap_content for their heights.

My questions are -

1. How do I restrict the size of my fragments so it sticks to the fixed viewgroup at the bottom as it does not have a specific height?
2. Is this the best approach to implementing such a design where there is a fixed footer to swap between fragments?
3. How to create and add a re-usable UI component similar to something like a google card where I can push in data from the server and include those dynamically in the scrollview.

Thank you.

**Edit 1**

activity_main -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="dd.MainActivity" >

        <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llFooterPlaceholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/green" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llFooterMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/bottom_bar"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/state_definition_iv1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/state_definition_iv2" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/state_definition_iv3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/state_definition_iv4" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/state_definition_iv5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Scrollable item above footer -->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/llFooterPlaceholder"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <!-- Inflate the contents of the ScrollView dynamicaly -->
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment1 which is activated onClick of iv1 of the footer (layout not complete yet) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:background="#444"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/item_padding" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAvtar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="#000"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#0ff"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvImageTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#ff0"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimestamp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Timestamp"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:background="#999"
        android:padding="@dimen/item_padding"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:background="#000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivShare"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#ddd"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_padding"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your XML or Efforts please.

Comment: @SilentKiller Added what it currently looks like, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ScrollView` height from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`. Because `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` your ScrollView come over your `llFooterPlaceholder`

like this

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/llFooterPlaceholder"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <!-- Inflate the contents of the ScrollView dynamicaly -->
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am thinking of moving the scrollview to the fragments itself, and populating then adding a reusable layout (the skeleton of which is in the fragment xml) by code. I am a bit confused to exactly I should go about it. Also, I am not so sure whether such a footer is actually the best approach to such a design.

Comment: Normally i prefer to replace my Fragments in FrameLayout which is in my main.xml and scrollview will be in my Fragment.xml. and if you move ScrollView to the Fragment file that will be good but you need to keep `android:height="wrap_content"` where you replace your Fragment in `main.xml`

Comment: When I attach the fragment, how can I specify the height so that it does not overlap my footer (which has wrap_content as height)?

Comment: in which layout you will attach Fragment show me that code please.

Comment: I plan to attach the fragments in the activity_main only, in place of the scrollview, and move the scrollview to the fragment layout. The child elements of the scrollview will be multiple card like layout which are populated by code and then inflated inside the scrollview.

Comment: I used a FrameLayout to drop in my fragment layout. Thanks.

Comment: one advice : try to check and try samples available on developer.android.com about all views. :)